# Instruct google chrome to use a specific input device programatically

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I need to instruct google chrome to use a specific input device programatically, without me having to go manually, or with a tool like selenium, to microphone settings and select it. Basically when the application starts it should already be configured to the input device I want. Changing the system default device won't do the trick, cause I'll be starting multiple chrome instances and each should pick a different mic. Is there a cli argument for me to achieve this? Or can I somehow specify that in user data dir? Or any other way?